# How can I calculate skewness via Xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray, resampling, skew

I found the amazing capability of xarray to perform variable resampling and mean, and standard deviation calculations.

Is there a direct way to calculate skewness after temporal resampling of data just like with the .mean() method?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xarray.DataArray.reduce()` setting the `func` argument to `scipy.stats.skew:`

```
import scipy.stats
import xarray as xr

airtemps = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")
temp_skewness = airtemps.air.resample(time="1M"
                                      ).reduce(func=scipy.stats.skew,
                                               dim="time")
```